# Java: Can an Observer be notified of changes through a hierarchy of observers?

Tags: java, observer-pattern, runnable, observable

So I have a few classes that are just Observers, another that is both an Observer and Observable, and a third that is just Observable.

I want to be able to take the class that is both and notify some of the Observers that the class that is only Observable has changed. So, the Observer and Observable class doesn't actually change itself, but notifies the Observers when the Observable only one does (and thus, gets the observers to run their update method).

Is this something possible to do? Is is it a must to change the Observable in order to make it notify the observers? How would I even go about this?

Edit: I discovered the issue with my design:

When the update method takes an Observable o, I wasn't ensuring whether this o was an instance of ObserverObservable or ObservableOnly, so problems arose from that. I had to make conditions for both and create an instance of ObservableOnly or a class/methods that gets information from Observable only to be a field within Observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As earlier stated, it is definitely possible.

I took some time to write some simple code, where I use java interfaces for both the observer and the observable. (I guess it's worth mentioning that I'm using the poll version of observer, not push.)

http://pastebin.com/M2CY82wd

The code is not perfect, but hopefully it shows you what it could look like.

Also, here is a book that I, and many others,  recommend:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this.

Some questions you should ask yourself to clarify your design:

- Why should the Observer-only class not observe the Observable-only class directly?
- How can the Observer-only class learn about details of how the Observable-only class changed?
- Is the Observer-and-Observable class only responsible for forwarding the update notifications, or has it also some other role in your design?

Comment: So, to your first question. . .what if I would like it to be able to do both things?

Answer (score 0):

Codewise, I see no problem having a class that has the behavior of both an observer and a subject. If you're working with interfaces, the observer/observable should just implement both interfaces.

To have both behaviors in one class should not be a problem if your overall implementation is clean, Feel free to submit some code, and we can comment on it from a Design Pattern point of view.

Comment: What do you mean by both interfaces? The only interface is the Observable one.

Comment: One common approach is to have an interface for the observable, and one for the observer. While the observable interface might have several methods, such as "notifyAll", "register" and "unregister", the observer interface usually just have the "notify" or "update" method to implement.

This is of course no necessity, but it's a nice way to structure dependencies in a program.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I read about something that might be of use but haven't implemented it myself.

In brief you would be creating a 'linked observer' chain where each observer can hold a 'observer' variable next_, and when you notify the observer of change you would recursively walk through linked Observers.

```
while (observer != NULL)
{
  observer.onNotify(entity, event);
  observer = observer.next_;
}
```

The actual article that read was here;
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html#linked-observers